# ASP.NET MVC Routing with child route without Attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Lets say I want use URL like http://localhost/Controller/1/ChildController/Edit/1 to access the child record(s) of a parent record in ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

Using Attribute Routing we can route like below.

```
[Route("Controller/{id:int}/ChildController/Edit/{childId:int}")]
public ActionResult EditChildRecord(int id, int childId)
{
    return View();
}
```

How to achieve same in convention-based routing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need it to create a areas.
Create a new area, and set your controllers there. A area will be equivalent to your main controller and the controllers to yours child's controllers.

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/area-in-asp.net-mvc